# Get link of the clicked image in a webview

Tags: java, android, webview

I want to get the link of an image clicked inside a Webview to display it in an new intent. The site that i want the image from is not opening the images in fullscreen when clicked.
I want something like the code down bellow but the website doesn't open images in the same tab.

Reference Code:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
if(url == null){
  return false;
}else if (url.trim().toLowerCase().endsWith(".img")) {//use whatever image formats you are looking for here.
  String imageUrl = url;//here is your image url, do what you want with it
}else{
  view.loadUrl(url);
}
 }
}
```

Comment: share your code in your question , so we can help you

Comment: I want something like this but like I said the website that i want the image from dosent open them in new windows it just make them bigger and that's why i want the clicked image link.

Comment: yes it can be done but you need to share your code buddy here

Comment: ok so , now you want to go to new activity and load in webview this url ?

Comment: Yes, i want to get the image link and load the link in a new activity's webview, but that i can handle that. I just want the link of the image...

Comment: check the answer , i think this is what u wated , and upvote

Comment: I don't have access to Android Studio now but when i will try the code i will upvote it. Thanks!

Comment: sure let me know if you need any help if face any error !

Comment: Massi GamingRo thankyou mate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
if(url == null){
return false;
}else if (url.trim().toLowerCase().endsWith(".img")) {//use whatever 
image formats you are looking for here.
 String imageUrl = url;//here is your image url, do what you want with 
 it
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
//pass from here the data to next activity and load there
intent.putExtra("yourURL", imageUrl);

startActivity(intent)

}else{
view.loadUrl(url);
 }
}
}
```